# Serving image files from the database to the template

Tags: python, django

I am stuck trying to figure out how to serve images files from a GET Request on a button in my html document; when the button is clicked it loads the image to the page. The files are stored in a directory for example: `/model/modelrun/region/myimage.png` I understand that the path to the image should be stored in the database:

page.html:

```
<div class="btn-group btn-group-justified" role="group" aria-label="...">
            <form action="#" method="GET" class="navbar-form navbar-left" role="form">
                <div class="btn-group" role="group">
                    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">GFS</button>
                </div>
            </form> 
</div>
            <iframe src="{% url 'new_model_image' }" ></iframe>
```

models.py:

```
from django.db import models

class NModels(models.Model):
    model_name=models.CharField(max_length=30)

class Modelrun(models.Models):
    currmodel = models.ForeignKey(NModels)
    run_name = models.CharField(maxlength=20)

class MRegion(models.Models):
    model_run = models.ForeignKey(Modelrun)
    region = models.CharField(max_length=20)

class ModelImages(models.Model):
    finalmodel = Models.ForeignKey(MRegion)
    timestep = models.IntegerField(max_value=3)
    picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=pathtomyimagefiles)
```

Reasoning: Every model will have multiple model runs of different regions where there will be multiple images for a given time step (maybe I need to separate these last two).

views.py:

```
def model_page(request):
    if request.method =='GET':
          [get image path and load into iframe]                 
    return render(request, 'models.html')
```

Here's where I get lost with trying to use the GET request to get the path to the image to the database to load into the iframe.

Comment: `picture = models.ImageField(upload_to:pathtomyimagefiles)` should be `picture = models.ImageField(upload_to=pathtomyimagefiles)`

Comment: Where are you expecting the image path to come from?

Comment: There should be no quotes in {% url 'new_model_image' }

Comment: @Brandon My intention is that after running the scripts that generate the images I would be able to save the image path to the database something like tmpmodel=NModels(model_name='gfs') ... model_images=ModelImages(timestep=3, picture='pathtomyimagefiles') tmpmodel.save(), model_images.save().

Comment: @TanaySoni That is incorrect. Functions referenced by the url tag must appear in quotes: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/templates/builtins/#url

Comment: You would need to pass the `ModelImages` instance back to the template and reference the `picture.url` field in your iFrame src. Alternatively, you could pass this URL back via ajax and set the src without reloading the view.

Comment: @Brandon that makes sense. I'm confused about connecting all of the pieces together. Right now my scripts that generate the images are not connected with my django app. I'm just test single file in the folder. Would it make sense to import the view into my image generating scripts and save the paths that way?

Comment: I'm not quite understanding what you're wanting to do. Are you wanting to upload the image via your form and then reference the path?

Comment: @Brandon Yes. The image already exists in the directory. I want to be able to click the button and load the image into the iframe. At the moment i'm just trying with one button, but eventually eventually I will have many that will need a path reference to upload the image to the iframe.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/79875/discussion-between-brandon-and-wxcoder).